# Defining a suitable Euclidean Ring s.t. $\exists a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ st $512a + 972b = 4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm

The question is as follows:

> By deﬁning a suitable Euclidean ring, prove that there exist two
>   integers a and b such that 512a + 972b = 4, explaining your reasoning
>   clearly. (Note: you do not need to obtain speciﬁc values of a and b.)

I assume that I need to somehow use the fact that if $d=\gcd(a, b)$ then $\exists\lambda, \mu$ st $d=\lambda a+ \mu b$

So if I manage to show that $4=\gcd(512, 972)$, then I can use the above statement.

How do I show that $4=\gcd(512, 972)$ and how can I define a suitable Euclidean Ring?

Obviously $4|512$ and $4|972$ and I thought maybe I could consider $4\mathbb{Z}$ to be the Euclidean Ring...but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: You have the unique factorisation property in $\mathbf Z$.

Comment: You can take the Euclidean ring $\mathbb{Z}$ with $d(x)=|x|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Euclidean algorithm for $512/4=128$ and $972/4=243$ in the Euclidean ring $\mathbb{Z}$. We have $gcd(128,243)=1$, and the Euclidean algorithm gives $$128\cdot(-112)+243\cdot 59=1.$$ Then multiply this equation by $4$.

Comment: However the question seems to imply that I can show that there exists two such numbers $a$ and $b$ without actually working them out. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Yes, the existence is guaranteed by the Euclidean algorithm. See [Bezout coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_identity).

Comment: Hmm I see, and how did you conclude that $gcd(128, 243)=1$?

Comment: I concluded it by the Euclidean algorithm, i.e., by dividing $243$ by $128$. Of course, anyway $gcd(2^7,3^5)=1$ because $gcd(2,3)=1$.